# PHP halts output of data on apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a php script that pulls some data from a database and displays it in XML format. For some reason it halts output when it gets to an apostrophe in the data. This is a SELECT statement, and a simple one at that, so I don't understand why there are any issues with apostrophes or quotation marks. I've tried using addslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string(), even though my understanding is that those are for sanitizing data being inserted into the database, and it did not help. I'm stumped. Below is the code and thanks in advance for any advice!

```
<? if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl)){
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ ?>
<slide>
    <id><?= $row->id ?></id>
    <title><?= $row->title ?></title>
    <chatter><?= $row->description ?></chatter>
    <image><?= $row->path ?></image>
    <link><?= $row->href ?></link>
    <active><?= $row->active ?></active>
</slide>
<? }
}else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

EDIT:
It turns out I have misunderstood the problem. They are not apostrophes but instead are right single quotes. If I change them to actual apostrophes the script works but I still don't understand why it doesn't simply output them though.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. *"It halts output"* is not an error message.

Comment: Are you sure that the apostrophes were actually inserted into the database?

Comment: @rdlowrey Error reporting is on. It returns no error. kolink: My issue isn't just that the apostrophe's aren't showing up, it's that it's not continuing once it gets to them.

Comment: You appear to not understand the format of XML. Only one outer tag...

Comment: @ColeJohnson Even if that were true it is in no way helpful. And this is just a snippet. <slide> is not the outer tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `str_replace("'", "\'", $field_to_be_replaced);`

You can replace the `'` char with a blank space if you prefer, just for testing.

Comment: Unfortunately since there are no apostrophes in the output to find this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

the apostrophe **(')** is an invalid character for *XML*!
You must call `$safe_string = str_replace("'","&apos;",$string)` in all your fields before
outputting the .XML file.

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to learn about these characters and build a more complete [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

**EDIT:**

What im using:

```
// save ubercart products in XML
function replace_characters_for_xml($str) {
   return str_replace(
      array("&",">","<","'",'"'),
      array("&amp;","&gt;","&lt;","&apos;","&quot;"),$str
   );
}
...
$row->title = replace_character_for_xml($row->title);
$row->href = replace_character_for_xml($row->href);
...
```

Comment: I didn't realize. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem but is useful information nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: check edited post and tell me if it fixes anything. Otherwise we'll go for SimpleXMLElement solution.

Comment: This isn't true. Apostrophe is a valid character. The only invalid characters in PCDATA sections are ampersand, less-than, and the character sequence ']]>'. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax

Comment: Thanx for the link but apostrophe and double quotes are _invalid_ for attributes. As you see in my answer, im replacing attributes, where apostrophe and double quotes are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it halts on the output of the data, and not when the data is processed? Apostrophe's have special meaning in XML, so if they are included in your XML data you have to replace them with an entity reference. There are 5 predefined entity references in XML, for less than, greater than, ampersand, apostrophe, and one for quotation mark. Alternatively, you can mark the text as CDATA so that the XML parser doesn't try to parse it.

Try making your program output the XML data to a text file instead of to wherever it is going now. Does it still halt on the apostrophe? If not, then it's definitely because of a problem parsing the data. If your program still halts on the apostrophe even when outputting the data only to a text file, there may be a problem somewhere else in the program where that data is processed. Check all the references to the variable containing the data, and see if you can find the exact line the program breaks on.

Comment: The program does still halt even when outputting to plain text but I didn't realize the apostrophe had special meaning within an XML tag so this is still useful to me. Thanks!